# Set cookie from subdomain A for subdomain B

Tags: jquery, http, nginx, cookies, cross-domain

from `http://subdomain-a.my-site.com:3000`, I make a cross domain XHR (ajax) call to `http://subdomain-b.my-site.com`.

My jQuery client has the following settings (for testing purpose):

- `crossDomain = true` -> for requesting other domains
- `withCredentials = true` -> for accepting `Set-Cookie` headers from ajax calls

The Nginx server has been configured to add the following headers in the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://subdomain-a.my-site.com:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

The HTTP Response also contains some `Set-Cookie` headers with the following domains :

- *.my-site.com*
- No domain precised (expecting the Endpoint domain: *subdomain-b.my-site.com*)

Observation:

- Chrome's console does not show CORS problem with this configuration.
- After receiving the HTTP Response, I went to `chrome://settings/content/cookies`, and there's zero cookie set for `subdomain-a` or `subdomain-b`.

**Question => Am I trying to do something possible or impossible ? If it's possible, did I miss some configuration ?**

Constraint:
I know there's an alternative solution, like Google Analytics does for setting cookie (it call a service then set the cookie from the embedded JS in your page), but we have a lot of front apps and cannot update them to do this trick. Our solution is to use nginx.

Comment: It's not possible to set cookies across subdomains. A page can only have cookies set in its own domain or a parent.

Comment: Show what is the `Set-Cookie` response coming as in the browser network tools

Answer (score 3):

**It's possible**. I missed the following configuration :

`withCredentials = true` is wrong, `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}` was the solution.

About the HTTP Response, we have the following `Set-Cookie` headers:

```
Set-Cookie: authtoken=value; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: authtoken=value; Domain=.my-site.com; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

Now, if you go to *subdomain-b.my-site.com* and open the cookie's tab, you'll see a `authtoken` cookie with the *subdomain-b.my-site.com* domain. This was tested with Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Note:
`crossDomain = true` is unnecessary, because our XHR HTTP Response returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://subdomain-a.my-site.com:3000`. But `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}` is mandatory with jQuery.

Comment: tnx @Gugelhupf, i have a question, set Domain=.my-site.com will set cookie for all subdomains, is it possible to set cookie from a.example.com for exact b.example.com?

Comment: By default no (for security reasons), but you can do **explicit** configuration for allowing `a.example.com` setting cookies of `b.example.com`: add the required HTTP headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` + `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and configure your JS client from `a.example.com` to accept cross-domain cookies.

Comment: tnx, i did the configurations but setting domain to "b.example.com" didnt work, sounds like it just works when domain is ".example.com"

Comment: It will work if you have set your domain to `.example.com`, that's a normal behaviour, nothing special here. It should also work with `b.example.com` if your configuration is correct, I think you missed something either server side with the HTTP response headers or JS client side options for accepting cross-domain cookies.